# Do all meta stackoverflow bug, feature request, and discussion eventually get reviewed by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Not sure if it was written somewhere or mentioned in the podcast, but I had expectation that if I write something in the uservoice, eventually one of the moderators would review the case and write one-liner. Even if the request was unpopular.

Can the users of meta stackoverflow expect the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I periodically review...

#### Highly voted bugs with no status assigned

[https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=bug%20-status-~&sort=votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=bug%20-status-%7E&sort=votes)

#### Highly voted all feature requests with no status assigned

[https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=feature-request%20-status-~&sort=votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=feature-request%20-status-%7E&sort=votes)

If you want something implemented, then vote for it!

I also highly recommend you check out what is currently planned as well.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned

Answer (score 4):

First, I think that while Jeff said that he would try to review all feature requests, he hasn't made any promises about responding (or even reading) all of them. In any case, what you really want is to get community feedback regarding your feature request, and that's something that I think can be done a lot more effectively here than on UV. Once you start accumulating replies and upvotes the team will definitely start to pay attention.

Personally, as a moderator here, I am going to try to review as many posts and feature requests as I can, but again I make no promises about providing feedback.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I understand that you don't want to make any promises, but I was wondering about unpopular requests that get no upvotes. On UV, you'd eventually get rejected by Jeff or other moderators, which is better than no response.

Comment: Well there has been a sort of love/hate relationship between the SO team and UV. I remember for the first few months (August-Octoberish) you would very rapidly receive a response from the team. Then there was a period of about 2 months (October-December) with virtually no activity. Things picked up a little with the appointing of the UV mods, but as of now unless you can drum up some support for your suggestion, or unless it was a bug, it is usually ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is still a little to early to tell how this thing is going to play out.

It could become completely irrelevant, or it could be the major force for improvements on all of the sites.

*Actually as I write this the first question says it was asked 19 hours ago.*