# Is it acceptable to re-raise an issue that was closed as status-bydesign at a time when SE's requirements were different?

Tags: discussion, bug-reports

As a particular example, [WMD unable to render markup inside words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/wmd-unable-to-render-markup-inside-words) was closed as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) back in 2009, when Stack Exchange didn't exist, and Stack Overflow was a site exclusively for programmers. Now that Stack Exchange exists, there are parts of the network (like Japanese.SE, where intra-"word" bolding is used and tokens like `word_word_word` aren't) that have requirements that I'm sure Jeff never anticipated when he gave [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19004/224428) to that question.

Would it be acceptable for me to raise that issue again as either a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on MSO?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144650/can-old-features-ever-be-changed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106860/what-is-meta-protocol-for-re-requesting-ignored-feature-requests