# Why all feature requests are not taken into consideration?

Tags: discussion, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't all bugs and feature-requests have moderator status tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60505/why-dont-all-bugs-and-feature-requests-have-moderator-status-tags)

I was going through [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) made until now. I was amazed because there were above 10k requests are made until now. It was good but there were above 70% feature-requests are not having [moderator tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/47640#47640) about its status. There are many feature requests which are 2-3 years ago having still not moderator tags. There might be many feature requests are completed or declined or in progress. But no way to see through moderator tags.

So my questions are:

1. Whose responsibility to check [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag?
2. Does all [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) are taken into consideration?
3. How much maximum time it (should) take to [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag have [moderator tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/47640#47640)?
4. Is there any other way to know feature request is taken into consideration other than [moderator tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/47640#47640)?

**Edit**:

There are above [2500 bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=bug%20-status-~&sort=votes) and above [8000 feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=feature-request%20-status-~&sort=votes) not having attention. There are many posts having above 50 votes. But there is no any moderator tags to it. [According to Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23685/178505) they are looking high voted bugs and feature requests.

1. How much votes bug or feature request should have to get attention?
2. Can we flag those posts for moderator attention by custom message?

Comment: Dupe?: [Why don't all bugs and feature-requests have moderator status tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60505/why-dont-all-bugs-and-feature-requests-have-moderator-status-tags) related: [Do all meta stackoverflow bug, feature request, and discussion eventually get reviewed by a moderator?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/do-all-meta-stackoverflow-bug-feature-request-and-discussion-eventually-get-re)

Comment: 1. Everyone; 2. Not really; 3. 6-8 weeks; 4. If no Dev comments/answers, no.

Comment: @Bart: 3rd, 4th and 2 subquestions after reading links given by you are remained.

Comment: 1. At least so much that you can open a bug report for it because the score does not display correctly any more; 2. Whatever-place-of-eternal-pain-you-believe-in no! Mod != Dev.

Comment: @ Garden Gnobobby: 3. 6-8 weeks. There are questions which are asked 2-3 years before and not still having moderator tags.

Comment: 2. Nope, 3. No exact figure, 4. Nope (As indicated by @GardenGnobobby really). 6-8 weeks is a standard expression here btw, meaning "We have no real figure for you".

Comment: [Well,it's just from the top of his head](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/136489).

Comment: With regards to your *"Can we flag those posts for moderator attention by custom message?"*, I would say don't. A moderator can not do a whole lot about it (if anything at all). If you really feel it's critical, then you could always offer a bounty to get it some attention. I have done so recently. It got some more attention, but didn't get picked up. There is no guarantee.

Comment: So there is no guaranty when bug or feature request will be picked up. :(

Comment: Is there ever such a guarantee?

Comment: @UristMcBobby: At least old questions should status changed. There are some questions having same feature whose request are made many times. After changing status we can understand plan of feature.